# JS: why is the var not declared when it is declared inside a method of an object and passed as a parameter to the other method of the same object?

Tags: javascript, declaration, var

I don't know why I get the error "ReferenceError i is not declared", when the variable is declared inside a method of an object and passed as a parameter to the other method of the same object.

This is my JS:

```
var reservasAPP = {   
    generarGrilla: function(){
        //la llamo desde el html con jQuery(document).ready();
        for(var i=1; i<13; i++){
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"return reservasAPP.guardarReserva(i);\">Reservar</button>");
        };
    },
    nombre: function (i) {
        return $('#horario'+i).val();
    },  
    guardarReserva:function(i){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario'+i).html('--> '+this.nombre());
        console.log("whatever "+i);
        console.log(i);
        return false;
    },    
}

window.reservas = reservasAPP;
```

If I go to the console and try to get the value of var i typing "var i", I get "undefined". Why is undefined?

Comment: it would help to tell us exactly which line is causing the problem...

Comment: p.s. you have jQuery - please use that to attach proper event handlers instead of using "inline" `onclick` handlers.

Comment: Ah, and that explains your problem.  The `i` in that `onclick` handler has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with the `i` in the loop.

Comment: Why it has nothing to do with the onclick in the for loop? Aren't both the same i variable inside the same method?

Comment: The string `return reservasAPP.guardarReserva(i);` of  `onclick=\"return reservasAPP.guardarReserva(i);\"`  is evaluated in the global scope at the time the click takes place. So this `i` is not related to the `i` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var reservasAPP = {   
    generarGrilla: function(){
        //la llamo desde el html con jQuery(document).ready();
        for(var i=1; i<13; i++){
            var impresionGrilla = $('#grilla').append("<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"return reservasAPP.guardarReserva(" + i + ");\">Reservar</button>");
        };
    },
    nombre: function (i) {
        return $('#horario'+i).val();
    },  
    guardarReserva:function(i){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario'+i).html('--> '+this.nombre(i));
        console.log("whatever "+i);
        console.log(i);
        return false;
    },    
}
```

**Explanation**
`"<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" onclick=\"return reservasAPP.guardarReserva(i);\">Reservar</button>"` is injected into the DOM but the variable "i" has no meaning there.

Also, the "nombre" function requires an argument which should apparently be the argument passed into the "guardarReserva" function. Therefore the following line has been changed:

`var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario'+i).html('--> '+this.nombre());`

to

`var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario'+i).html('--> '+this.nombre(i));`

Comment: please don't encourage inline DOM0 handlers - they're error prone for exactly this reason (amongst others) and also require that the invoked handler be in the global scope (which is bad practise)

Comment: @Alnitak, I was not encouraging DOM0 handlers. I was merely re-posting the original code with a modification that gets it working. Which, by the way, had nothing to do with the embedded `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `generarGrilla` function with this:

```
generarGrilla: function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++){
        $('#grilla').append('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">')
                    .on('click', this.guardarReserva.bind(this, i));
    }
},
```

The code above replaces the inline DOM0 event handler with a jQuery-registered handler.

That handler is generated by the `.bind` call, that not only ensures that `guardarReserva` is called with the correct `this`, but also passes the current value of `i` is passed as the first parameter to that function.

[ Within `guardaReserva()` you also need to remember to pass `i` when you call `this.nombre()`, i.e. `this.nombre(i)` ].

Answer (score 1):

If that i variable you are trying to use here:

> nombre: function (i)
>
> guardarReserva:function(i)

It the same i declared  here:

```
generarGrilla: function(){
//la llamo desde el html con jQuery(document).ready();
for(var i=1; i<13; i++){
```

That i it's only defined within the scope of the generarGrilla function that's why you get the "ReferenceError i is not declared" error.

Comment: actually, no - whilst that is indeed a bug, it's not the one the OP is seeing.